# Cannot access SharedPreferences in constructor

Tags: android, android-preferences

I use `SharedPreferences` for storing data.  When I try to call the data-storing function  from the constructor of my class, it shows a Runtime error.  However, when I call the function from onCreate() it works fine.
Is there any way I can call my data-storing function from the constructor?

```
package com.examples.storedata;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity1 extends Activity 
{
    EditText editText1, editText2;
    TextView textSavedMem1, textSavedMem2;
    Button buttonSaveMem1, buttonSaveMem2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1);
        textSavedMem2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem2);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        buttonSaveMem1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem1);
        buttonSaveMem2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_mem2); 
        buttonSaveMem1.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener);
        buttonSaveMem2.setOnClickListener(buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener);
    }

    public Activity1()
    {
        LoadPreferences(); //show error while calling from here
    }

    Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveMem1OnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SavePreferences("MEM1", editText1.getText().toString());
                LoadPreferences();
            }
        };

    Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveMem2OnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SavePreferences("MEM2", editText2.getText().toString());
                LoadPreferences();
            }
        };


   private void SavePreferences(String key, String value)
   {
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putString(key, value);
       editor.putInt("1",5);
       editor.commit();
   }

   private void LoadPreferences()
   {
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
       String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
       String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
       textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
       textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access your text views before you have initialised the view or the variables:

```
textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
```

When you call `LoadPreferences` from the Activity constructor, `onCreate` hasn't yet been called, which means `textSavedMem1` and `textSavedMem2` have not been initialised and are `null`.

When you call it from `onCreate`, so long as it is after the following, then these variable are initialised and everything works as expected.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main); 

textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1);
textSavedMem2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem2);
```

Comment: but thing is that when i declared that textSavedMem1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.savedmem1); in the contructor than also it doesnt work..

Comment: That's because the constructor is the wrong place to do that. You should _only_ initialise UI elements in `onCreate`. The reason it doesn't work is because you haven't called `setContentView`. Now, while you may technically be able to do that in the constructor, I would expect you to have other problems since Android isn't ready for you to start working on the Activity until it calls `onCreate`. Until Android has called `onCreate`, you literally do not have an activity that you can interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible since u can get `SharedPreference` in activity which has already been created.. here u r trying to get SharedPreference even before activity is under construction (Constructor).. for getting shared preference u need `activity`..

U can store the values in some Instance variables inside constructor then put them in SharedPreference...

Comment: That means we there is no option for calling it from a constructor

Comment: can i used other storing method like SQLLite internal storage to solve this problem

Comment: can you please help me with an example

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. By the time your activity is created e.g when the constructor is called SharePreferences object is not yet accessible. It's not good practice to use/override activity's constructor. Read about [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) to get the idea how to use activity.